# Android Bluetooth LE Scan always returns -2.147483648E9 for rssi

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am trying to measure the distance to an iBeacon on a Galaxy Tab 4 (Bluetooth 4.0) performing a BLE Scan. The rssi data I am receiving seems to be wrong. It is always at -2.147483648E9.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ScanFilter mScanFilter;
    private ScanSettings mScanSettings;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findBeaconClickListener();

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();


    }

    public void findBeaconClickListener() {
        setScanFilter();
        setScanSettings();
        Button findBeacon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findBeacon);
        findBeacon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(Arrays.asList(mScanFilter), mScanSettings, mScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setScanFilter() {
        ScanFilter.Builder mBuilder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
        ParcelUuid pUUID = ParcelUuid.fromString("0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
        mBuilder.setServiceUuid(pUUID);
        mScanFilter = mBuilder.build();
    }

    private void setScanSettings() {
        ScanSettings.Builder mBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
        mBuilder.setReportDelay(0);
        mBuilder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER);
        mScanSettings = mBuilder.build();
    }

    protected ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            ScanRecord mScanRecord = result.getScanRecord();
            int txPower = mScanRecord.getTxPowerLevel();

            String deviceName = mScanRecord.getDeviceName();

            int mRssi = result.getRssi();
        }
    };
```

So when I read this rssi value from the result it's somehow wrong. The devicename and txPower seem to be ok.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you change the scan type to LOW_LATENCY?

Comment: No it is the same issue.

Comment: The rssi is an integer. How could you get a float value?

Comment: its not a float: -2.147483648E9 is actually −2.147.483.648 which is the smallest number possible for a signed 32 bit integer.